# How to convert string '0x900x100xe8' to Buffer in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am working on a project in which a microcontroller device sends data to a web server.

I have created a webpage in which a user can send commands to the device using the form and can see the response from the device on the same page.

The problem is the device only understands hexadecimal commands. So I need to send hexadecimal commands from the page like

**0x800xe80x10**

Now I can read the user submitted command from the form on webpage but I am unable to convert it to hex as it is. I've read about Buffer but it changes the each ASCII character to a hex. So **0x80** gives something like

30 78 38 30

while I want is to be

80

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buffers can be passed hex data, they just don't expect `0x` before each byte, so you can do this:

```
var userHex = '0x800xe80x10';
var buf = new Buffer(userHex.replace(/0x/g, ''), 'hex');
// buf == <Buffer 80 e8 10>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hexStr2Buf(hexStr) {
    var hexArray = hexStr.split('0x').filter(function(e) {
        return e.length === 2;
    });

    var numArray = hexArray.map(function (e) {
        return parseInt(e, 16);
    });

    return Buffer(numArray);
}

var buff = hexStr2Buf('0x800xe80x10');

console.log(buff);
```

output:

```
<Buffer 80 e8 10>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to send that command to the server side, use:

```
var buf = new Buffer([128, 232, 32]);
console.log(buf);
```

where 128, 232, 32 is 0x800xe80x10. Any other method would introduce redundancy

Comment: no it was just an example. The string will be entered by the user. So it can be anything.